# Creating a new table with data from tables of varying size

Tags: powerbi

Hi I have two tables one has a large number of orders with a column for date. The second table has one column labeled month and another with hours making for 12 rows in total. I want to make a new column by dividing the count of orders per month by the hours of that month from the second table.

In excel i'd simply countif orders that are in January from the first table and divide by the hours in January from the second.

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to make this new table with calculated values from the existing tables.

Thanks for your time.

Below is  a picture of table 2. The first table is a standard dataframe with thousands of rows.

[image: Table 2]

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

You can use the "Append Query" and create a new table that is combining all of your data.

You can also use CALCULATE(SUM(table[field]), filter(table, table[field] = table[monthfield]) /SUM(table[field])

If you could give an example of what you have, I could definitely show you how to accomplish this.

[image: SOLUTION]

Here is a link to the solution file. One by merging data, and one by using CALCULATE(SUM(),FILTER())

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yxpv62Dnv8LSNW_mxibPfL0aCMrepoCU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How would appending be useful here? This is a lookup scenario, so Append will not help at all.

Comment: oh i could use that calculate example and filter both fields by month that would give me a value for each month. I would have to have 12 measures that way though. Is there a cleaner way to get the data? I want to have a graph of orders/hours for each month in the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could append based upon a month field, and then you have two columns that you can calculate and then sum all the based on month. I'll put together an example file and post

Comment: Added solutions in original answer.

Comment: Ive made some progress i can make a column in table 2 that calculates number of orders for 1 month. How do i get this formula to increment from 1 to 12?


Total_column=CALCULATE(COUNT(Table1(date),MONTH(Table1(date)=1)


id like the column to increment the month value so i have totals for all 12 months down the column instead of a column of January totals.

Comment: Table1(date)=[Month], just direct the calculate statement to look at the column instead of a value of 1